# Control Animation with Slider or Progress Control In Cocos-2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

- I want to perform an timing controlled Animation using **CCMoveTo**
  Functions and **CCspritesheets.**
- But,My critical point is that I want to update the each and every progress of the Animation in Some Slider Control.
- Also, the user has the ability to change the slider's progress
  manually.It means the slider's change should accordingly synchronize
  with the animation's status.

  In short , the animation should be controlled with the slider's progress like the progress bar controls the frame's timing in a
  video.

  How to proceed with this idea? Sorry for poor documentation. Please guys join hands.

Comment: Cocos2d Animation :-
http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/downloads/detail?name=cocos2d-iphone-2.0-alpha.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Hope this helps !!
Good luck..

Comment: Core Animation :-
http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-extensive-core-animation-techniques-demo/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But, I am sorry the above code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/downloads/…  project uses the asynchronous animation . 
And the  maniacdev.com/2011/08/… link uses UIKit and Core Animation .But  i want to implement this with CoCos2D .

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think that you can do this with standard cocos2d actions and standard action manager of cocos2d. You can try to implement your own actions that will not be run with

```
[someNode runAction: action];
```

because in this case action will be managed by action manager. So, your own action class will be almost the same as standard action class, just it will receive updates not from action manager, but from your slider's value. I mean, that updates of cocos2d actions are normalized, so there is no difference because of duration.